# display all the correspondingstate values in dropdown based on another text field dropdown in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-templates

Here when country name is given in the text field display all the states in the dropdown list

Here is my html code

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label pull-left" for="coubtry">Sales order</label>
        <div class="controls">
             <input name="country_name" type="text">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label pull-left" for="capacity">Items</label>
       <div class="controls">
           <select name="states">
               <option value="">-----</option>
                      ( How to display the states in dropdown based on country given above??)      
           </select>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here country is given in text and i need the states in dropdown list

Comment: To me, this question is very unclear. What are you trying to achieve? What have you done so far? What exactly is not working? Besides that, change `vlaue` in your option tag to `value`.

Comment: Actually what i am trying to achieve is in my modal pop up when the user enters the country it automatically need to display all the states of that country ...where for country is a text ..the above html code is a part of my modal pop up code